# Opera Profiling gives me no data

Tags: profiling, opera, opera-dragonfly

[image]I tried to use opera dragonfly for opera next using the instructions given [here](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/profiler/).
But I get "No data" displayed when I stop recording.
Any idea on the issue?

Uploaded the issue snapshot

Answer (score 0):

The profiler records events that take place **after** the record button is pressed. Do one of the following:

- Reload the page
- Make an AJAX request
- Trigger a mouse or keyboard event